# BASH: filter huge list of numbers if they are contained in another huge list

Tags: bash, filter

Lets say I have two CSV files. First one is of format:

```
id(unique int),owner_id(non-unique int),string
```

It contains 50-100 millions rows. Few GBs.

Second one has format:

```
integer,integer
```

Second file contains something like billion rows. I want to get all the rows of File 2, where both first and second column value exists somewhere in first file second column (owner_id).

Most efficient way would be to get the unique values of the owner_id in memory, order and do binary search for each pair from the second file. I don't know if something like this can be done with BASH, I could do it with python (supply a simple script the two files, it will read, load them, and spit second file with all the valid pairs).

However I'd like to not add dependency of python, if possible.

Comment: How sparse is the owner_id? If it is rather dense, you can sort owner_id and only remember the missing ids.

Answer (score 1):

This may fall over due to memory constraints.
I have called the files file1 which has the 3 columns and file2 which has the IDs
Copy and paste the code segments into a file and edit names as appropriate.

Step one: Make file 1 as small as possible.

```
#/bin/bash
declare -a Array
Count=0
```

The first an third columns are not needed, so remove them, Sort the file then grab only unique entries.

```
InitFile ()
{
while IFS=, read ignore1 stuff ignore2; do  echo $stuff ; done < file1| sort -n | uniq >  $1
}
```

Read into an array:

```
InitArray ()
{
   while  read  Array[$Count]; do
     let Count++
   done < $1
}
```

Binary Search for a value in the array:

```
BinarySearch ()
{
   val=$1
   let idx=$Count/2
   top=$Count
   bottom=0
   while true; do
      if [ ${Array[$idx]} -eq $val ]; then return 0; fi
      lastIdx=$idx
      if [ $top  -le $bottom ]; then return 1; fi
      if [ $val -lt ${Array[$idx]} ]; then top=$idx && let idx=$idx/2;
      elif [ $val -gt ${Array[$idx]} ]; then bottom=$idx && let idx=($top+$bottom)/2; fi
      if [ $idx -eq $lastIdx ]; then let bottom=$bottom+1 ; fi
   done

}
```

uniqueOwnerIdFile will be created from the first file then put into the array

```
InitFile uniqueOwnerIdFile
InitArray uniqueOwnerIdFile
```

Loop through each line of the second file and look for both values in the owner ID array. Echo every one that is found to linesTheExistFile.

```
while IFS=, read firstVal secondVal; do
   if BinarySearch $firstVal && BinarySearch $secondVal ; then echo "$firstVal,$secondVal" ; fi
done < file2 > linesThatExistFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a solution in pure bash, but i can provide one using `awk`:

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{col3[$2]++;next;}{ if ($1 in col3 && $2 in col3) print $0} ' File1 File2
```

First read the 2nd column of the first file into an associative array and then look for each row of the second file wether they are in the array or not.

Answer (score 0):

In bash something like this might work.

```
#!/bin/bash

list=$(cut -f2 -d, file1.txt | sort -u)

while IFS=, read a b; do
  [[ $list =~ $a && $list =~ $b ]] && echo "$a,$b"
done <file2.txt >result.txt
```

I'm not too sure about performance, though.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution. It remembers all the owners form file 1 in a hash, than goes over file 2 and outputs the lines where both owners exist in the hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $F1, '<', 'file1' or die $!;
my %owner;
while (<$F1>) {
    $owner{(split /,/ => $_, 3)[1]} = 1;
}

open my $F2, '<', 'file2' or die $!;
while (my $line = <$F2>) {
    chomp $line;
    print "$line\n" if 2 == grep exists $owner{$_}, split /,/ => $line, 2;
}
```

Bash pipeline, that gives the same output, but is significantly slower:

```
cut -d, -f2 file1 \
    | grep -vwFf- <(sed 's/,/\n/' file2) \
    | grep -vwFf- file2
```